# Does "liking" posts on facebook via PHP api have call limit?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have created a page for my app and I have users with facebook accounts in my system making posts to facebook. What I would like to achieve is to use my page to like these posts on facebook.

I have implemented all the functionality and it works fine programmatically, but after ~20 consequential $facebook->api("/$id/likes", "post"); calls I start to get "(#1705) There was an error during posting." exceptions. After I let it cooldown for a day these posts can be liked again.

I thought that maybe I have stressed the facebook servers, so I added sleep(few seconds) in between every api call. This allowed me to post ~300 posts before i reached same error. I still get the error an hour later.

Is there a chance I am hitting some kind of undocumented call limit?

Comment: I'd say it's safe to assume that there are limits to API calls. I do not believe that the specific limit is published as that would make it possible for people to ride on the edge of the limit but never hit it - that kind of cancels the whole idea of limiting...

Comment: You can read up on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/) about Facebook's API rate limiting, it's in the ads-api section but it does mention other types of rate limits.

Comment: If it would be the case of an actual limit, why would facebook give so ambiguous error message. I have other apps that tell me that I have reached a limit when I have. In given case it just tells that there is an error. If that is implemented to prevent spam, why not tell that given action is suspicious and/or prohibited? Or perhaps they are really experiencing issues- i wonder why would graph api explorer then successfully work with these calls. I'm abit confused.

Comment: I agree with you that an appropriate message should be displayed... Keep in mind that this very well might be a bug on their side and the error message you get might change at some stage... The fact that you were able to post more requests when you placed a slight delay between calls really hints to me that you're hitting a limit... but that's just a guess...

Comment: Perhaps you should [open a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/trending/) with Facebook - this might really be a problem on their side...